# How do I properly use Clipboard in a console application?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, clipboard, topshelf

I am a C# beginner and I am trying to create a Windows Service (Console Application with Topshelf) (.Net Framwork 4.8) that gets and sets the clipboard every second (yes, useless service, it's just for learning).

When using System.Windows.Forms as reference in my service class the Timer class stops working ("'Timer' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' and 'System.Timers.Timer'") and the application throws System.Threading.ThreadStateException at the lines where I'm using the Clipboard class: "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made, ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it".

```
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClipboardProject
{
    public class TimerClipboard
    {
        private readonly Timer _timer;

        public TimerClipboard()
        {
            _timer = new Timer(1000) { AutoReset = true };
            _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
        }

        private void TimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            string userClipboard = Clipboard.GetText();
            Clipboard.SetText($"Latest copy: {userClipboard}");
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            _timer.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edited:**

This is my main method.

```
using System;
using Topshelf;

namespace ClipboardProject
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var exitCode = HostFactory.Run(x =>
             {
                 x.Service<TimerClipboard>(s =>
                 {
                     s.ConstructUsing(timerClipboard=> new TimerClipboard());
                     s.WhenStarted(timerClipboard=> timerClipboard.Start());
                     s.WhenStopped(timerClipboard=> timerClipboard.Stop());
                 });

                 x.RunAsLocalSystem();
                 x.SetServiceName("Random ServiceName");
                 x.SetDisplayName("Random DisplayName");
                 x.SetDescription("Random Description");
             });

             int exitCodeValue = (int)Convert.ChangeType(exitCode, exitCode.GetTypeCode());
             Environment.ExitCode = exitCodeValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A service is an extremely hostile place for such code.  Beyond the zero practically of the user having their clipboard content destroyed once a second, the approach simply cannot work by design.  Services run in the in/famous [session 0](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/ba-p/372361), isolated from the desktop session.  The proposed solution cannot work either, a DispatcherTimer cannot tick without a dispatcher.  This problem doesn't need to be solved, best to move on to the next project.

Comment: I have not heard about session 0. I will definitely read more about it. Interesting to read. However, even though the application is both dangerous and useless, I would appreciate if someone can help me solve this…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed` handler always running in background thread, so `Clipboard` OLE calls causes `System.Threading.ThreadStateException`.

You can handle it by creating new `System.Threading.Thread` and force it to start as STA thread by `SetApartmentStart(ApartmentState.STA)`, but this is **unefficient**, **horrible** and **wrong** solution:

```
private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
    {
        string userClipboard = Clipboard.GetText();
        Clipboard.SetText($"Latest copy: {userClipboard}");
    });

    t.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
}
```

because on each interval tick it would create new `Thread`. `Thread`s take huge performance-cost, especially if created in loops.

So, the correct solution may be in usage of `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` from `PresentationFramework` library:

```
public class TimerClipboard
{
    private readonly System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer _timer;

    public TimerClipboard()
    {
        _timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        _timer.Tick += OnDispatcherTimerTick;
    }

    private void OnDispatcherTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userClipboard = Clipboard.GetText();
        Clipboard.SetText($"Latest copy: {userClipboard}");
    }

    public void Start() => _timer.Start();
    public void Stop() => _timer.Stop();
}
```

About *"'Timer' is an ambiguous reference between `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and `System.Timers.Timer`"*: that's because both namespaces has class `Timer`, so your Studio doesn't know which one you want and need to use. It can be solved by removing another `using` or with explicit specifying:

```
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;
// or
using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;

namespace ClipboardProject
{
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT.**

As @Hans Passant noticed, `DispatcherTimer.Tick` event couldn't fire without dispatcher, so upper solution won't work with Topshelf. So I offer to rewrite `TimerClipboard` class to remove any timer from there and use simple flag-based `while` loop. As there no timer, I renamed it to `ClipboardWorker`.

Complete solution looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Topshelf;

namespace ClipboardProject
{
    class Program
    {
        // Add STA attribute to Main method
        [STAThread] 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var topshelfExitCode = HostFactory.Run(x =>
            {
                x.Service<ClipboardWorker>(s =>
                {
                    s.ConstructUsing(cw => new ClipboardWorker());
                    s.WhenStarted(cw => cw.Start());
                    s.WhenStopped(cw => cw.Stop());
                });

                x.RunAsLocalSystem();
                x.SetServiceName("ClipboardWorkerServiceName");
                x.SetDisplayName("ClipboardWorkerDisplayName");
                x.SetDescription("ClipboardWorkerDescription");
            });

            Environment.ExitCode = (int)topshelfExitCode;
        }
    }

    public class ClipboardWorker
    {
        // Flag that would indicate our Worker in running or not
        private bool _isRunning;
        private int _interval = 1000; // Default value would be 1000 ms

        public bool IsRunning { get => _isRunning; }
        public int Interval 
        { 
            get => _interval;
            // Check value which sets is greater than 0. Elseway set default 1000 ms
            set => _interval = value > 0 ? value : 1000;
        }

        // Constructor
        public ClipboardWorker() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("ClipboardWorker initialized.");
        }

        // "Tick" simulation. 
        private void DoWorkWithClipboard()
        {
            // Loop runs until Stop method would be called, which would set _isRunning to false
            while (_isRunning)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(); // <--- just line break for readability

                string userClipboard = Clipboard.GetText();
                Console.WriteLine($"Captured from Clipboard value: {userClipboard}");

                Clipboard.SetText($"Latest copy: {userClipboard}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Latest copy: {userClipboard}");

                // Use delay as interval between "ticks"
                Task.Delay(Interval).Wait();               
            }
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            // Set to true so while loop in DoWorkWithClipboard method be able to run
            _isRunning = true;
            Console.WriteLine("ClipboardWorker started.");
            // Run "ticking"
            DoWorkWithClipboard();          
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            // Set to false to break while loop in DoWorkWithClipboard method
            _isRunning = false;
            Console.WriteLine("ClipboardWorker stopped.");
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: I copied your solution and the code compiles without exception but the OnDispatcherTimerTick is never called...?

Comment: Did you start it by calling `new TimerClipboard().Start();`?

Comment: I have now updated my post with my main method. I tried to comment out all code and only write timerClipboard = new TimerClipboard().Start(); but it didn't compile since Start() is a void type @Auditive

Comment: Separate initialize and start. Initialize: `TimerClipboard tc = new TimerClipboard();`. Then start timer: `tc.Start();` Or combine initialize and start without assigning to any variable: `new TimerClipboard().Start();` (not `var tc = new TimerClipboard().Start();`)

Comment: Not working. Another user commented on my post that the proposed solution cannot work "The proposed solution cannot work either, a DispatcherTimer cannot tick without a dispatcher. "

Comment: I've edited answer with another solution way. About `DispatcherTimer.Tick` event here need a bit more time for research and test.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could call the Windows native user32 clipboard functions `GetClipboardData` and `SetClipboardDat` (pinvoke)

A C# wrapper library can be found here https://github.com/MrM40/WitWinClipboard/tree/main